# C# - Run code in background and continue with current method

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am new to async/await in C#. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
private async Task LoadSomeData()
{
    /*
    *This is where the 'Data' is loaded with HTTP
    */
    //Data loading finished. Need to return control to next line from caller function and use this 'Data'

    // Also need to use 'Data' to load 'Data2' over HTTP but is not very important
    // and hence can be run in background. No piece of code depends on this currently.
}

private async void UIEventHandler()
{
    //await until 'Data2' has loaded
    //Continue handling the event after Data2 is loaded
}
```

My question is, how do I achieve the above operation. I don't want to return from `LoadSomeData()` method after retrieving Data2 as the current operation does not depend on it.

Comment: What code have you actually tried and how did it behave?

Comment: Create a new async task?  In win32 I'd just PostMessage the second task.

Comment: I would probably split `LoadSomeData` in two

Answer (score 2):

Below is some quick code I threw together around your method names. I've made them static just for convenience.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main Start");

        UIEventHandler(2000);
        UIEventHandler(500);
        UIEventHandler(1000);

        Console.WriteLine("Main Stop");

        Thread.Sleep(3000); // wait for tasks to finish
    }

    private static async Task LoadSomeData(int delay)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start (LoadSomeData) " + delay);
            Thread.Sleep(delay);
            Console.WriteLine("Stop (LoadSomeData) " + delay);
        });
    }

    private static async Task UIEventHandler(int delay)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start (UIEventHandler) " + delay);
        await LoadSomeData(delay);
        Console.WriteLine("Stop (UIEventHandler) " + delay);
    }
}
```

This is sample output from a test run:

```
Main Start
Start (UIEventHandler) 2000
Start (LoadSomeData) 2000
Start (UIEventHandler) 500
Start (UIEventHandler) 1000
Main Stop
Start (LoadSomeData) 500
Start (LoadSomeData) 1000
Stop (LoadSomeData) 500
Stop (UIEventHandler) 500
Stop (LoadSomeData) 1000
Stop (UIEventHandler) 1000
Stop (LoadSomeData) 2000
Stop (UIEventHandler) 2000
```

You will notice that every call to `UIEventHandler` showed it's "Start" message straight away. However, the "Stop" message is not shown until the respective call to `LoadSomeData` is complete. The `await` operator is essentially telling the code in `UIEventHandler` to stop until the task in the called method is complete.

That's a really simplistic view of it, though. I'd suggest doing some reading. This might be a good start:
[Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

Answer (score -1):

```
private async Task LoadSomeData()
{
    var data = await Task.Delay(1000); // Replace with your HTTP GET
    return data;
}

private async Task LoadSomeData2(Data data)
{
    var data2 = await Task.Delay(1000); // Replace with your other HTTP GET
    return data2;
}

private async void UIEventHandler()
{
    var data = await LoadSomeData();
    var data2 = await LoadSomeData2(data);
}
```

**UPDATE**:
I recommend you read [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The `LoadSomeData` method is called in the constructor whereas `UIEventHandler` is quite literally a UI event handler. In this handler, I need to wait here until `LoadSomeData2` is finished. However, I want to call `LoadSomeData2` ealier and have it run in the backgroud so that the UI handler would not have to wait long

Comment: You cannot await inside a constructor therefore you cannot call LoadSomeData inside a constructor. Unless you are blocking in the constructor by calling LoadSomeData().Wait() which would be a terrible idea. First because that mixes synchronous and asynchronous code which you should not do, and second because don't make your constructor do async operations, expose an async method for that.